# Timer or doWakefulWork crash when attempt to set/use activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, timer

I assume the problem stems from the same thing.  Whether i call this sub from a fired timer or a doWakefulWork, i get a crash...

```
TextView Past = (TextView) ((Activity) ctx).findViewById(R.id.past);
Past.setText(Html.fromHtml(dMsg));
```

In my code, i go so far as to make sure the user has that activity active so that i am not just displaying a activity out of the blue.  In my doWakefulwork, i am grabbing some an html result, and based on the retrieved data, i want to display a particular activity.  It does not crash when i obtain the value of Past.  It crashes when i try and `setText`

Why am i running into this trouble...

HERE IS MY ERROR WHEN USING THE WAKEFUL

Thread [<15> IntentService[PageP]] (Suspended (exception ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException))
    WakeWork(WakefulIntentService).onHandleIntent(Intent) line: 112 
    IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(Message) line: 65
    IntentService$ServiceHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 137 
    HandlerThread.run() line: 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer #1 was very true.  If you are using a SERVICE and within that service are utilizing a timer or a WakefulIntentService, these can be running on a different thread.  Most importantly, a thread different from your UI (User Interface) thread.  Any modifications to any activities must be done on the UI thread.  Once i added in the below code to my timer, I was able to successfully process my activity changes.

```
public static void TickTockHit() {
    ((Activity)Login.ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
     {
        public void run()
     {
       Login.ShowForm("");
      }
     });    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, that is not a complete stack trace. That is Eclipse capturing the exception. Please run past the point of the exception in Eclipse, then use LogCat to get the full stack trace.

Second, a `Service` should not be trying to manipulate widgets of some activity directly. Ever.

Third, nobody, not even an activity, can modify widgets from a background thread, such as the one used by an `IntentService`.

At this point, I'm guessing that a `Service` is probably not the right model for you, and you should be doing something else from the activity (e.g., `AsyncTask`).

If you are convinced that a `Service` is the correct solution, then you need to have the `Service` send a message to the activity (or relevant fragment) about data changes, using:

- `LocalBroadcastManager`, or
- an event bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), or
- a `Messenger` tied to a `Handler`
- etc.

Comment: Asyntask works just fine and is what i was using.. But, i was having issues with the program going away.  I have tasks that must run every 20 seconds.  If certain messages come in, and the user has an active activity displaying, then i update the view on that activity.  

I started with timers, then moved to alarms.  Alarms worked great except the program wasnt staying awake long enough to retreive the async tasks.  So, i moved on to the Wakefulserviceintent.  This seems to be the right way to go.  By utilizing the RunonUiThread i was able to remedy the couple issues i was having.

Comment: @user2250168: "I have tasks that must run every 20 seconds" -- unless that is *only* being done when the activity is in the foreground, or *only* being done under user control (e.g., explicit start and stop buttons), then this is seriously bad. "This seems to be the right way to go" -- not for events every 20 seconds. "By utilizing the RunonUiThread i was able to remedy the couple issues i was having" -- except for all the other issues, like the memory leaks, that you're ignoring.

Comment: What would you suggest then?  No, the activities are done every 20 seconds regardless of whether or not the activity is in the foreground.  If the user does not have any activities active, then  notifications are created.  If the user has activities active, then activities are displayed with updated information.  When i get this stable, i would like to change the alarm to trigger every 60 seconds instead of every 20 seconds.

Comment: @user2250168: "When i get this stable, i would like to change the alarm to trigger every 60 seconds instead of every 20 seconds" -- you should change it to occur at a *user*-defined frequency. After all, it is their battery that you're hammering. For periods best measured in minutes, `AlarmManager` and `WakefulIntentService` are a reasonable answer. For periods best measured in seconds, you may as well keep the device on 24x7 with a `WakeLock`, use an everlasting service, and reap the one-star ratings as a result.